# How to round up value C# to the nearest integer?

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I want to round up double to int.

Eg,

```
double a=0.4, b=0.5;
```

I want to change them both to integer.

so that

```
int aa=0, bb=1;
```

`aa` is from `a` and `bb` is from `b`.

Any formula to do that?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the double is outside the range of int?

Comment: Rounding 0.4 to 0 is not rounding up. It is simply rounding.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling) to round up

```
Math.Ceiling(0.5); // 1
```

Use [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round) to just round

```
Math.Round(0.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 1
```

And [`Math.Floor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.floor) to round down

```
Math.Floor(0.5); // 0
```

Comment: You need to do more work with Math.Round. It provides an enum (MidpointRounding) to specify the behaviour accurately.

Comment: @jnielsen: Thanks for pointing that and for the code example. I've corrected it.

Comment: The simplest and effective way is Math.Ceiling

Comment: Please note that `Math.Ceiling` will return the same number if the number is already whole, it will NOT round up by 1

Answer (score 16):

Check out [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx).  You can then cast the result to an `int`.

Answer (score 11):

The .NET framework uses banker's rounding in `Math.Round` by default. You should use this overload:

```
Math.Round(0.5d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)  //1
Math.Round(0.4d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)  //0
```

Answer (score 5):

[Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round)

> Rounds a double-precision floating-point value to the nearest integral value.

Comment: However: "The behavior of this method follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. This kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's rounding. ..."

Answer (score 5):

Just some adjusting @BrunoLM's answer with more samples :

```
Math.Round(0.4); // =0
Math.Round(0.5); // =0
Math.Round(0.6); // =1

Math.Round(0.4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // = 0
Math.Round(0.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // = 1
Math.Round(0.6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // = 1

Math.Round(0.4, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // = 0
Math.Round(0.5, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // = 0
Math.Round(0.6, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a function in place of `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`:

```
myRound(1.11125,4)
```

Answer:- 1.1114

```
public static Double myRound(Double Value, int places = 1000)
{
    Double myvalue = (Double)Value;
    if (places == 1000)
    {
        if (myvalue - (int)myvalue == 0.5)
        {
            myvalue = myvalue + 0.1;
            return (Double)Math.Round(myvalue);
        }
        return (Double)Math.Round(myvalue);
        places = myvalue.ToString().Substring(myvalue.ToString().IndexOf(".") + 1).Length - 1;
    } if ((myvalue * Math.Pow(10, places)) - (int)(myvalue * Math.Pow(10, places)) > 0.49)
    {
        myvalue = (myvalue * Math.Pow(10, places + 1)) + 1;
        myvalue = (myvalue / Math.Pow(10, places + 1));
    }
    return (Double)Math.Round(myvalue, places);
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the current culture uses commas instead of full stops for the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Math.Round(0.5) returns zero due to floating point rounding errors, so you'll need to add a rounding error amount to the original value to ensure it doesn't round down, eg.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.5, 0).ToString()); // outputs 0 (!!)
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.5, 0).ToString()); // outputs 2
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.5 + 0.00000001, 0).ToString()); // outputs 1
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.5 + 0.00000001, 0).ToString()); // outputs 2
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: it doesn't matter for me..i also found out that.

Comment: There's no error.  1/2 can be represented exactly as a double.  The docs say, "If the fractional component of a is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the even number is returned."  0 is the even number.  This fudge factor will make numbers like 0.499999995 round wrong.

Comment: Cheers for the heads-up.  I was trying to ensure the OP knew that Round didn't work as simply as others were suggesting.  Thankfully the OP now knows to watch out for it, and I have a better understanding of Round myself. =)

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

```
string strVal = "32.11"; // will return 33
// string strVal = "32.00" // returns 32
// string strVal = "32.98" // returns 33

string[] valStr = strVal.Split('.');

int32 leftSide = Convert.ToInt32(valStr[0]);
int32 rightSide = Convert.ToInt32(valStr[1]);

if (rightSide > 0)
    leftSide = leftSide + 1;


return (leftSide);
```

Comment: Looks like some low-level coding, please, do not follow it :)

Answer (score -1):

It is also possible to round negative integers

```
// performing d = c * 3/4 where d can be pos or neg
d = ((c * a) + ((c>0? (b>>1):-(b>>1)))) / b;
// explanation:
// 1.) multiply:          c * a  
// 2.) if c is negative:  (c>0? subtract half of the dividend 
//                              (b>>1) is bit shift right = (b/2)
//     if c is positive:  else  add half of the dividend 
// 3.) do the division
// on a C51/52 (8bit embedded) or similar like ATmega the below code may execute in approx 12cpu cycles (not tested)
```

Extended from a tip somewhere else in here. Sorry, missed from where.

```
/* Example test: integer rounding example including negative*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   //rounding negative int
   // doing something like d = c * 3/4
   int a=3;
   int b=4;
   int c=-5;
   int d;
   int s=c;
   int e=c+10;


   for(int f=s; f<=e; f++) {
      printf("%d\t",f);

      double cd=f, ad=a, bd=b , dd;

      // d = c * 3/4  with double
      dd = cd * ad / bd;

      printf("%.2f\t",dd);
      printf("%.1f\t",dd);        
      printf("%.0f\t",dd);

      // try again with typecast have used that a lot in Borland C++ 35 years ago....... maybe evolution has overtaken it ;) ***
      // doing div before mul on purpose
      dd =(double)c * ((double)a / (double)b);
      printf("%.2f\t",dd);

      c=f;
      // d = c * 3/4  with integer rounding
      d = ((c * a) + ((c>0? (b>>1):-(b>>1)))) / b;
      printf("%d\t",d);
      puts("");
  }
 return 0;
}

/* test output
in  2f     1f   0f cast int   
-5  -3.75   -3.8    -4  -3.75   -4  
-4  -3.00   -3.0    -3  -3.75   -3  
-3  -2.25   -2.2    -2  -3.00   -2  
-2  -1.50   -1.5    -2  -2.25   -2  
-1  -0.75   -0.8    -1  -1.50   -1  
 0   0.00    0.0     0  -0.75    0  
 1   0.75    0.8     1   0.00    1  
 2   1.50    1.5     2   0.75    2  
 3   2.25    2.2     2   1.50    2  
 4   3.00    3.0     3   2.25  3    
 5   3.75    3.8     4   3.00   

// by the way evolution: 
// Is there any decent small integer library out there for that by now?
```

Answer (score -2):

It is simple. So follow this code.

```
decimal d = 10.5;
int roundNumber = (int)Math.Floor(d + 0.5);
```

**Result is** 11

Comment: why use `Math.Floor` when the OP wants to round to nearest? This won't work for negative values

Comment: This example only for positive values.

Comment: you didn't even mentioned that in your question. And the OP didn't say that he's only interested in positive integers. Anyway this is useless because there are already Math.Round