# Can Math.Round in C# be used for whole integer values?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have integer 363 for example.

Any method to make it 360 or 365?

Comment: do you want it 360 or 365? (rounded up or down)

Comment: your_num % 5 == 0 ? your_num : your_num + (your_num % 5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, you're just going to have to code the logic yourself. Here's one such method. (Going down is clearer, but going up is manageable.)

```
int number = 363;
int roundedDown = number - number % 5;
int roundedUp = number + (number % 5 > 0 ? (5 - number % 5) : 0);
```

**Edit** for negative numbers, the logic almost gets reversed.

```
static int RoundUpToFive(int number)
{
    if (number >= 0)
        return number + (number % 5 > 0 ? (5 - number % 5) : 0);
    else
        return number - (number % 5);
}

static int RoundDownToFive(int number)
{
    if (number >= 0)
        return number - number % 5;
    else
        return number + (number % 5 < 0 ? (-5 - number % 5) : 0);
}
```

Comment: @Ani, didn't check for negatives. Will muddy the water a bit.

Answer (score 8):

This is a hack, but it works:

```
var rounded = Math.Round(363 / 5f) * 5;
```

Comment: I m sry. But I simply dun know wht is 5f?

Comment: It specifies 5 as a float value.  It has the same meaning as `(float)5`.  You have to divide using a floating-point value, or the result will be truncated as an integer, and will subsequently always round down.

Comment: Note that this will evaluate to a `double` when the OP was (probably) looking for an `int`.

Comment: Throwing this in an extension method would be kick ass. Then you just round out the integer. ` var i = 363 ` then ` i.rounded() ` to get what you need.

Comment: @John: No reason it can't be casted to `int`.

Comment: @cdhowie - right on, just wanted to make it obvious because it looks like the OP is relatively new to C# (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920553) and with `var` it could be confusing at first

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I usually do, which is a combination of the two ideas:

```
static int RoundDown(int x, int n) {
    return x / n * n;
}

static int Round(int x, int n) {
    return (x + n / 2) / n * n;
}

static int RoundUp(int x, int n) {
    return (x + n - 1) / n * n;
}
```

(That assumes positive numbers; Extending it to negatives is straight-forward.)

[edit]

According to LLVM, the Round function can also be written like this:

```
int Round(int x, int n) {
    int z = (x + n / 2);
    return z - (z % n);
}
```

Which you may find more elegant.