# Approximate percentage in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [round up value C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920553/round-up-value-c-sharp)

I want to approximate percentage in ASP.net, for example I had a percentage 72.72727272727% I want it to be approximated to 73%, how can I do that in ASP.net

Comment: Do you want to change the value in code-behind, or do you just want to display it rounded but leave the underlying value alone?

Comment: I want only to display the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lnPercentageRnd = Math.Round(72.72727272727, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

The AwayFromZero is important for natural rounding, because .Net defaults to Banker's Rounding.

Answer (score 2):

It's not specific to ASP.NET, but .NET in general.

```
double d = .7272727272727;

string percent = d.ToString("p0"); // 73%
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Percentage = Math.Round(Percentage)
```