# How to Round to the nearest whole number in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

How can I round values to nearest integer?

For example:

```
1.1 => 1
1.5 => 2
1.9 => 2
```

"Math.Ceiling()" is not helping me. Any ideas?

Comment: Math.Round() can do the trick.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round up value C# to the nearest integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920553/how-to-round-up-value-c-sharp-to-the-nearest-integer)

Answer (score 243, accepted):

See the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx) for more. For example:

Basically you give the `Math.Round` method three parameters.

1. The value you want to round.
2. The number of decimals you want to keep after the value.
3. An optional parameter you can invoke to use AwayFromZero rounding. (*ignored unless rounding is ambiguous, e.g. 1.5*)

Sample code:

```
var roundedA = Math.Round(1.1, 0); // Output: 1
var roundedB = Math.Round(1.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Output: 2
var roundedC = Math.Round(1.9, 0); // Output: 2
var roundedD = Math.Round(2.5, 0); // Output: 2
var roundedE = Math.Round(2.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Output: 3
var roundedF = Math.Round(3.49, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Output: 3
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/iFPLoR)

You need `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` if you want a .5 value to be rounded up. Unfortunately this isn't the default behavior for `Math.Round()`. If using `MidpointRounding.ToEven` (the default) the value is rounded to the nearest **even** number (`1.5` is rounded to `2`, but `2.5` is also rounded to `2`).

Comment: on the other hand, using `away from zero` also means that `-1.5` will round to `-2`.

Comment: use Math.Ceiling, its not a good practice to use Math.Round for frictions, read:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221205/why-does-system-midpointrounding-awayfromzero-not-round-up-in-this-instance,

Comment: I am finding that Math.Round(1.5, 0) returns 2

Comment: @davogotland is their anyway to round 137.5 to 140 not to 138 ? I mean rounding to nearest tenth ?

Comment: @sam perhaps divide by 10, then round with Math.Ceiling, and finally multiple by 10?

Comment: @DavidSykes I submitted an edit with some clarifications, because the behavior described was totally incorrect. 1.5 with `MidpointRounding.ToEven` (the default) will round to 2 and not 1 as was described. As MSDN states, `ToEven` rounds a midpoint like 1.5 to the nearest *even* number, 2.

Answer (score 77):

```
Math.Ceiling
```

always rounds up (towards the ceiling)

```
Math.Floor
```

always rounds down (towards to floor)

what you are after is simply

```
Math.Round
```

which rounds as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/in-c-math-round2-5-result-is-2-instead-of-3-are-you-kidding-me)

Comment: is their anyway to round 137.5 to 140 not to 138 ? I mean rounding to nearest tenth ?

Answer (score 8):

You need `Math.Round`, not `Math.Ceiling`. `Ceiling` always "rounds" up, while `Round` rounds up or down depending on the value after the decimal point.

Answer (score 7):

there's this manual, and kinda cute way too:

```
double d1 = 1.1;
double d2 = 1.5;
double d3 = 1.9;

int i1 = (int)(d1 + 0.5);
int i2 = (int)(d2 + 0.5);
int i3 = (int)(d3 + 0.5);
```

simply add 0.5 to any number, and cast it to int (or floor it) and it will be mathematically correctly rounded :D

Comment: It still looks suspicious. 
Firstly, the question asks about rounding *up* and secondly, when I tried it just now, the default implementation of Math.Round(1.5) rounds to 2. So this may not be what he wanted.

Comment: also, your example mixes decimal point with decimal comma. Which one do you normally use (in Sweden, I guess)? :)

Comment: oops... oh yeah, sorry. in programming the decimal point of course, but in formal text we use the decimal comma. and yes, sweden ^^ about the question, and the "rounding up" part: i think that's just some language mistake. in the examples given by op, some decimal numbers round down.

Comment: @ver i don't round down with Math.Round, i do it with a cast. that's why this way is manual and kinda cute ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Math.Round as others have suggested (recommended), or you could add 0.5 and cast to an int (which will drop the decimal part).

```
double value = 1.1;
int roundedValue = (int)(value + 0.5); // equals 1

double value2 = 1.5;
int roundedValue2 = (int)(value2 + 0.5); // equals 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a reminder. Beware for double.

```
Math.Round(0.3 / 0.2 ) result in 1, because in double 0.3 / 0.2 = 1.49999999
Math.Round( 1.5 ) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the Math.Round function that does exactly what you want.

```
Math.Round(1.1) results with 1
Math.Round(1.8) will result with 2.... and so one.
```

Comment: What about `1.5` as the value? You need more parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Math.Round(number)` rounds to the nearest whole number.

Answer (score 2):

this will round up to the nearest 5 or not change if it already is divisible by 5

```
public static double R(double x)
{
    // markup to nearest 5
    return (((int)(x / 5)) * 5) + ((x % 5) > 0 ? 5 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this, but my example was to take a number, such as 4.2769 and drop it in a span as just 4.3.  Not exactly the same, but if this helps:

```
Model.Statistics.AverageReview   <= it's just a double from the model
```

Then:

```
@Model.Statistics.AverageReview.ToString("n1")   <=gives me 4.3
@Model.Statistics.AverageReview.ToString("n2")   <=gives me 4.28
```

etc...

Comment: I'm using this your method because I also need a string and .ToString("n0") takes care of rounding for me: 1.5m.ToString("n0")  // returns "2"

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.math.round.aspx):

```
double roundedValue = Math.Round(value, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var roundedVal = Math.Round(2.5, 0);
```

It will give result:

```
var roundedVal = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your working with integers rather than floating point numbers, here is the way.

```
#define ROUNDED_FRACTION(numr,denr) ((numr/denr)+(((numr%denr)<(denr/2))?0:1))
```

Here both **"numr"** and **"denr"** are unsigned integers.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own round method. Something like,

`function round(x)
    rx = Math.ceil(x)
    if (rx - x <= .000001)
        return int(rx)
    else
        return int(x)
end`

Answer (score 0):

this is what I was actually looking for

```
float myRound(float numberIn, int numDig) 
{ 
    // float numberIn: number to round
    // int numDig: number of digits after the point
    // myRound(123.456,2) => 123.45
    // myRound(123.456,1) => 123.4
    // myRound(123.456,-1) => 120
    float tenPow = Mathf.Pow(10, numDig);
    return ((int)tenPow*numberIn)/tenPow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of normal rounding, round up, and round down

```
                        if (Overtime_Policy == "Overtime, Normal Rounding") { Calculated_Hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(UnRounded_Hours, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); }
                        if (Overtime_Policy == "Overtime, Round Down") { Calculated_Hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(UnRounded_Hours)); }
                        if (Overtime_Policy == "Overtime, Round Up") { Calculated_Hours = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(UnRounded_Hours)); }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
decimal RoundTotal = Total - (int)Total;
if ((double)RoundTotal <= .50)
   Total = (int)Total;
else
   Total = (int)Total + 1;
lblTotal.Text = Total.ToString();
```