# Rounding difference between decimal and money in .Net and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is the result from linqpad.

```
decimal d = .035m + .035m + .035m; 
d.Dump();
decimal.Round(d,2).Dump();
0.105
0.10
```

Here is the result from SMSS.

```
declare @d money
set @d = convert(money, .035) + convert(money, .035) + convert(money, .035)
select @d, round(@d,2)
(No column name)    (No column name)
0.105   0.11
```

What gives?

Comment: `money` data type is deprecated long time ago. That's the difference.

Comment: What else have you researched so far? Could it be that one defaults to "round even" (for 5) and the other defaults to "round up" (for 5)?

Comment: Looks like Round by default rounds down: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8844698/1073631 -- Try adding MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Comment: @sgeddes It doesn't round down, it rounds to even. But the solution is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The right answer is:

- C#'s [round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4e2bye2.aspx) rounds midpoint to the nearest even integer
- T/SQL's [round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) rounds midpoint up

---

**The below answer is wrong but perhaps instructive** 
A SQL constant like `0.1` is a `decimal` not a `float`, like hvd comments.

---

In C#, you're entering `0.35m` as an exact `decimal` constant with the `m` postfix.

But in SQL, you are converting `0.35` from `float` to `money`.  Conversions from `float` are not exact.  If you enter a money type using the prefix `$`, you get the same result as C#:

```
declare @d money
set @d = $0.035 + $0.035 + $0.035
select @d, round(@d,2)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2353/0)

Comment: Decimal constants have `numeric` data type in SQL Server, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530%28SQL.90%29.aspx#_decimal), not `float`.

Comment: And your online example gives `0.11`, which is not the result C# gives.

Comment: @hvd: You're right.  Any clue why `select 1.0 * 1 / 3` prints `0.333333` ?  Since `1.0` is a decimal with 1 scale, I'd expect the result to be `0.3`.

Comment: Contrary to the documentation (unless precision is not considered part of a data type), the result type of a division is not necessarily the type of either of `/`'s operands. Try `cast(1 as numeric(1, 0)) / cast(3 as numeric(1, 0))` for example. By my reading of the documentation, you're right, you should be getting `0.3`.

Comment: @hvd: Pretty unreal: [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2363/2)  This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) explains the rules, even why `1.0/3` results in a 6-scale decimal.

Comment: That's an interesting find, thanks for that. It seems to contradict [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx), which reads: "Result Types: Returns the data type of the argument with the higher precedence." Again, assuming precision is part of "data type". At least it is clear what actually happens now.

Answer (score 0):

@sgeddes answered it above.
Looks like Round by default rounds down: stackoverflow.com/a/8844698/1073631 -- Try adding MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero.