# How to round up a number to 2 decimals

Tags: c#, numbers, rounding

I'm trying to round up numbers using C# in a way that it always rounds to the next number. For instance:

```
0.409 -> 0.41
0.401 -> 0.41
0.414 -> 0.42
0.499 -> 0.50
0.433 -> 0.44
```

Is there a way to do this using .NET built-in functions?

Comment: *I'm trying to round up numbers using C#*  prove it  [ask]

Comment: @LuisFilipe: I'm not sure he will since he doesn't want traditional rounding...

Comment: @LuisFilipe And this will round 0.401 to 0.41?

Comment: I tried the obvious but I didn't get what I wanted.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8844674/1997232), see `Math.Ceiling` answer.

Comment: @LuisFilipe: The key thing about that is it is Midpoint Rounding. That is it is only used on the tiebreaker of whether a 0.5 goes to 0 or 1. It won't make a difference to 0.4 which Round will always put to 0 (assuming 0 decimal places on the round).

Comment: @user2506496: What do you consider to be "the obvious?" Including some of your code (especially that which isn't working) will improve your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used.

`Math.Ceiling` rounds to the nearest integer though, so I advise you do some division/multiplication also:

```
var notRounded = 0.409;
var rounded = Math.Ceiling(notRounded * 100) / 100;
```

Explanation: `notRounded` * 100 gives you **40.9**. `Math.Ceiling` will return **41**, so divide this again to 'restore it' back to the original decimal form: **0.41**.

Comment: Make sure to use `decimal` instead of `double`, since `double` is a floating point data type.

Comment: It worked, but could it be used to round to 1 decimal place too? For example: 0.401 to 0.5 instead of 0.41.

Comment: @user2506496: Then multiply and divide by 10.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48(v=vs.110).aspx) as [already described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26715549/993547).

Another option is to calculate the remainder, and add the difference to round up:

```
decimal r = 0.409M;
decimal d = r % .01M > 0 ? (r + .01M - r % .01M) : r;
```