# Round up values of text box in C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I want to Roun d Up Values Like This...

0.1 will be 0

0.3 will be 0

0.5 will be 1

0.9 will be 1

Is there any way to solve it in c#?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Have you tried anything? [Searching google perhaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844674/how-to-round-to-the-nearest-whole-number-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: textbox? - thats typically a string try `Math.Round(Double.Parse("0.1"))`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov no sir i have not tried anything..

Comment: @Henrik ok sir..sir but i'm really new in this so what is the role of Double.parse is?

Comment: @Nik going from strings to numbers.. string is objects that holds a list of characters, in this case: `"0.1" = '0','.','1','\0'` (4 characters, if old fashioned c-styled character array) or `"0.1" = 3, '0','.','1'` (1 length indicator, three characters if FORTRAN styled array) none of those data are possible to do math on. Double.parse tries to interpret a char array as a number.. it works if character array have a formatting, which corresponds to how you would write the number on screen. it fails if the string is "not a number"

Comment: @Henrik Ok Got it..Thank you for this brief explaination about that...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `Math.Round` you can read more about [Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx)

If the fractional component of number is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned. Note that this method returns a Decimal instead of an integral type.

and as suggested by @Micky you should be using `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` like

```
Math.Round(0.5d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

to get the correct output

Comment: Thank you for your Suggestion

Comment: If this solves. Accept it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the Decimal.Round method available in C#. For more info, please look at the following link,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Almost got it, but `Math.Round(0.5d)` returns `0` whereas OP wants `1`.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/jzwQYy

Comment: Thanks I will check this link

Comment: @Micky so is there any solution for this?